# Is there a way to get the item in a data table's row's specific column that isn't heavily dependent on strings?

Tags: c#, datatable, datagridview

I'm currently working on some very fragile code. It depends on lots of code like the following:

```cs
foreach (DataRow dr in MyDataTable.Rows)
{
    //The real version passes 20 arguments to Rows.Add
    MyDataGridView.Rows.Add(dr["foo"].ToString(), dr["bar"].ToString());
}
```

I'm aware that this code has numerous problems. For example, adding or removing a column in `MyDataGridView` means that I have to change/re-order all of my calls to `MyDataGridView.Rows.Add`. As much as I'd like a fix for that, there's one specific issue that I'd like to discuss here: The compiler has no way of knowing if the string-indexed columns, e.g. `"foo"` and `"bar"` exist. If I misspell one, I may not know until runtime. Is there a better - i.e. not "string typed" - way of indexing the columns of a DataRow?

Comment: _For example, adding or removing a column in MyDataGridView means that I have to change/re-order_ Why? The string indexing makes sure this will not be necessary.  - If you misspell a database column name you will also not know before runtime.

Comment: @TaW Because `MyDataGridView.Rows.Add` cares about the order that its arguments are written in. If you swap the first argument in my example with second, then `dr["bar"].ToString()` will go where `dr["foo"].ToString()` ought to be.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you should be able check the name of the column before processing the data.  i.e.

```
if ((dr.Table.Columns.Contains("foo")) && dr.Table.Columns.Contains("bar"))
{
    // We found both columns, allow processing;
    MyDataGridView.Rows.Add(dr["foo"].ToString(), dr["bar"].ToString());
{
else 
{ 
    // No column found, what should we do here?
}
```

Comment: Not great. That still only solves the problem at run time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of checking the existance of the column:

```
if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("foo"))
```

Another one checks the value, so you should be very careful in case the column exists but contains null:

```
if (row.Table.Columns["foo"] != null)
```

Comment: Don't both of these have the string-dependency that I'm trying to avoid?

Comment: What makes you suspecting this? `.ToString()` crashes on a null source. You check the source for null.

Comment: Suppose that you misspell `"foo"`. Is your error at run time or compile time?

Comment: No error if you add the checks.